# Fastlink Connection Reset Error

Tags: yodlee

Been unable to access Fastlink via the 'Developer Info' tab as well as from 'TestDrive' using Google Chrome as my browser. I keep getting a 'Connection was reset' error within the iframe. Its not consistent behavior with some attempts allowing me to add accounts. Tried using another computer and seeing same issues (both on the same wireless network). Are there any known issues on Yodlee's side? Please let me know if you need additional information from me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you were facing that issues temporary or intermittent.
In case if you still sees the issue, please do report to this on chat option available at developer.yodlee.com